# Dependency problems while installing Webmin

Tags: apt, dpkg, webmin

I'm having problems when installing **Webmin** for **Debian Wheezy**.

It turns out that, while installing the dependencies which are mentioned on these instructions from [Webmin website](http://www.webmin.com/deb.html), I receive the following error when installing **apt-show-versions**:

```
$ apt-get install apt-show-versions
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apt-show-versions is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? y
Setting up apt-show-versions (0.20) ...
** initializing cache. This may take a while **
Error: No information about packages! (Maybe no deb entries?)
dpkg: error processing apt-show-versions (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 255
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of webmin:
 webmin depends on apt-show-versions; however:
  Package apt-show-versions is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing webmin (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt-show-versions
 webmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Seems like that APT is having problems to process the configuration of the package.

Acoording to **"man apt"**:

> **--configure package...|-a|--pending**
>
> Configure a package which has been unpacked but not yet configured.  If -a or  --pending  is  given  instead  of  package,  all
>                unpacked but unconfigured packages are configured.
>
> To reconfigure a package which has already been configured, try the dpkg-reconfigure(8) command instead.
>
> Configuring consists of the following steps:
>
> 1. Unpack the conffiles, and at the same time back up the old conffiles, so that they can be restored if something goes wrong.
> 2. Run postinst script, if provided by the package.

I tried to...

- uninstall webmin and then installing apt-show-versions
- to clean APT cache

...but none of these options have solved my problem.

What kind of solution/workaround can I apply for this issue?

Answer (score 2):

```
rm /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/docker-gzip-indexes
apt-get purge apt-show-versions
rm /var/lib/apt/lists/*lz4
apt-get -o Acquire::GzipIndexes=false update
apt-get install apt-show-versions
```

Comment: Thank you - this worked for me.. phew

Answer (score 1):

I found [this solution](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/beagleboard/jXb9KhoMOsk) from this guy on the [BeagleBoard](http://beagleboard.org/) forum page at [Google Groups](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/beagleboard).

Here is the way that I chose to follow this procedure (here's the [Webmin package](http://www.webmin.com/deb.html)):

### purge apt-show-versions

```
apt-get purge apt-show-versions
```

### set on the fly option for apt

```
apt-get -o Acquire::GzipIndexes=false update
```

### apt-show-versions

```
$ apt-get install apt-show-versions
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
apt-show-versions is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 15 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 0 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
Setting up apt-show-versions (0.20) ...
** initializing cache. This may take a while **
```

### webmin

```
$ dpkg -i webmin_1.831_all.deb 
Selecting previously unselected package webmin.
(Reading database ... 13818 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking webmin (from webmin_1.831_all.deb) ...
Setting up webmin (1.831) ...
Webmin install complete. 
You can now login to https://e93cd8ed670b:10000/ as root with your root password, 
or as any user who can use sudo to run commands as root.

$ /etc/init.d/webmin start 
$ /etc/init.d/webmin status
Webmin (pid 4713) is running
```

### [explanations]

Acoording with [apt.conf man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/yakkety/man5/apt.conf.5.html):

> ...
>
> **THE ACQUIRE GROUP**
>
> The Acquire group of options controls the download of packages as well
>      as the various "acquire methods" responsible for the download itself
>          (see also sources.list(5)).
>   ...
>   ...
>
> **GzipIndexes**
>
> When downloading gzip compressed indexes (Packages, Sources, or
>      Translations), keep them gzip compressed locally instead of
>      unpacking them. This saves quite a lot of disk space at the expense
>      of more CPU requirements when building the local package caches.
>
> False by default **(doesn't seem to be the case for this situation).**

Probably, this version of **apt-show-versions (0.20)**, has a different behavior when dealing with GZIP compressed indexes and then, it is necessary to configure **"Acquire::GzipIndexes=false"** on the fly (apt-get update), or via **/etc/apt/apt.conf**, in order to follow with the installation of **apt-show-versions**..

Answer (score 1):

Here what worked for me:

```
dpkg --configure -D 777 apt-show-versions
```

result:

```
root@odroidserver:~# dpkg --configure -D 777 apt-show-versions
D000001: ensure_diversions: new, (re)loading
D000001: process queue pkg apt-show-versions:all queue.len 0 progress 1, try 1
D000040: checking dependencies of apt-show-versions:all (- <none>)
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> perl
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg perl:armhf
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> apt
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg apt:armhf
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libapt-pkg-perl
D000400:       checking non-provided pkg libapt-pkg-perl:armhf
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000400:   checking group ...
D000400:     checking possibility  -> libstorable-perl
D000400:       not installed
D000400:         returning 0
D000400:      checking provider libperl5.26:armhf
D000400:       checking package libstorable-perl provided by pkg libperl5.26:armhf
D000400:       is installed, ok and found
D000400:     found 3
D000400:   found 3 matched 0 possfixbytrig -
D000040: ok 2 msgs >><<
D000040:     checking Breaks
Setting up apt-show-versions (0.22.7ubuntu1) ...
D000002: fork/exec /var/lib/dpkg/info/apt-show-versions.postinst ( configure  )
** initializing cache. This may take a while **
Error: No information about packages! (Maybe no deb entries?)
dpkg: error processing package apt-show-versions (--configure):
 installed apt-show-versions package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 255
D000001: ensure_diversions: same, skipping
Errors were encountered while processing:
 apt-show-versions
```

In my case it pointed to an issue with package libstorable-perl. So I did:

```
apt-get purge apt-show-versions
apt-get update
apt-get install libstorable-perl
apt-get install apt-show-versions
```

voilá